# PHP htmlentities

Tags: php, html-entities

In htmlentities, how do I selectively encode the symbols so that it doesn't encode the `<` and `>` of tags but does encode `&`?

Comment: Are you talking about ".:;,!?"? If so, why do you want to encode them? Or are you talking about quotation marks?

Comment: 1. never use htmlentities. 2. never encode anything beside `<` and `>`, `&` and quotes.

Comment: The right solution to this problem is likely to be "Forget about encoding entities and just make sure you declare the character encoding you are using": http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
<?php
$string = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $string);
```

Refer [**this**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for details about str_replace from Official documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You don't get a ‘partially-encode’ option; if there are particular characters you want to be escaped or not escaped you will have to do it manually. For example to do what you *say* you want:

```
str_replace('&gt;', '>', str_replace('&lt;', '<', htmlentities($s)))
```

What is it you're trying to do, though? The above seems very unlikely to be useful. `"` characters in markup will still be escaped, mangling attribute values.

`htmlentities` is also in general questionable, because unless you specifically feed it the right charset argument it will mangle any non-ASCII characters in the string into wrong HTML entity references. It is usually better to use `htmlspecialchars()`, which only affects the few characters that really are special and need escaping in HTML.

If all you want to do is escape the `&` character you can do that with a simple `str_replace('&', '&amp;', $s)` but again, that would still replace ampersands that are part of a valid entity or character reference. Are you sure you want to do that? Are you just trying to fix up incorrectly-used unescaped ampersands? If so you could try a regex to select any use of a `&` that isn't a valid entity/character reference.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$string = htmlentities($string);
$string = str_replace(array('&lt;','&gt;'), array('<', '>'), $string);
```

At official documentation, [**htmlentities**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) and [**str_replace**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: err... in the second example, you forgot one parameter

Comment: @Col It looks like the original post wanted to use htmlentities to encode everything except for < and >

Comment: It looks like that the original poster have no idea what is he doing. Like many other posters. Do YOU see any sense in your answer? Why race to answer a poor question? Why to answer literally? We are not robots. We are humans. Who can think before act. At least supposed to.